# Semi Random pattern with Illustrator and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I want to create a camo like hex pattern in Adobe Illustrator with randomly generated patterns like this one which I found on the internet

[image: View Image]

I use a JavaScript to randomly color the hexagons in Illustrator and this is my result

[image: View Image]

As you can see, the first image has way more larger connected areas of one color. This is the JavaScript I'm using to color the hexagons

```
mySelection = app.activeDocument.selection;
myDoc = app.activeDocument;

if (mySelection instanceof Array)

{
selSwatches = myDoc.swatches.getSelected();

if(selSwatches.length != 0)
    for (i=0; i<mySelection.length; i++)
    {
        if(mySelection[i].typename == "PathItem" || mySelection[i].typename == "CompoundPathItem")
        {
            selItem = mySelection[i];
            selItem.filled = true;

            swatchIndex = Math.round( Math.random() * (selSwatches.length - 1 ));
            
            if(selItem.typename == "PathItem")
                selItem.fillColor = selSwatches[swatchIndex].color;
            else
                selItem.pathItems[0].fillColor = selSwatches[swatchIndex].color;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question: How can I alter the JavaScript to have more of the connected spaces?